# How does Django map the urls when there is ambiguity

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the url patterns in my project urls.py

```py
url(r'^', include('app.urls')),
url(r'^api/app/', include('app.url.router_urls')),
```

and in the `app.urls` i have something like

```py
url(r'^api/app/user$', views.user_validator),
```

and in the `app.url.router_urls` i have something like

```py
url('^v1/', include('app.url.app_v1.urls'))
```

I have a question around these.
so when the request is `BASE_URL/api/app/{user}` which url will be mapped to this?
and how about `BASE_URL/api/app/v1/` which url will be mapped.

this will map first with `^` right and will use the `app.urls` for both?

thanks

Comment: It takes the first view in the list that matches and thus "fires" that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django will fire the first view for which the URL matches. It thus evaluates the urls top-to-bottom.

It will thus first look to the included `app.urls` and if that matches (if you visited `hostname/api/app/user`, it will "fire" that view.

Note that here your user is *not* a variable, this is simply the word `user`, so if you visit `{user}`, it will keep looking, but since none of the patterns "fire", it will thus return a 404.

You can work with URL parameters, with:

```
url(r'^api/app/(?P<user>[\w{}]+)$', views.user_validator),
```

If we do this however, it will also match with `hostname/api/app/v1`, since then it sees that `[\w{}]+` matches with `v1`.

Therefore it is important to order the url patterns from more specific to less specific, or even better: design the URL patterns such that there is no *overlap*.

---

> **Note**: As of [django-3.1](/questions/tagged/django-3.1), [**`url(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#url) is
> deprecated in favor of [**`re_path(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/re-path).
> Furthermore a new syntax for paths has been introduced with path converters: you
> use [**`path(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/path) for that.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So if i go to `hostname/api/app/v1/` then it should fire `app.url.app_v1.urls`?

Comment: @Manojahirwar: it will look if there is a url in the `app.url.app_v1.urls` with an empty path. If that is the case then it will "fire" the corresponding view.